# Unknown type name error

Tags: c++, inheritance, member

I'm sure it's something obvious but I just can't see it: xcode is suddenly giving me all sorts of errors when I try to use my `Note` class (which is used very frequently).

Here's what the class header looks like:

```
class Note : public Playable{

private:

public:

    double theta;
    double frequency;
    int duration; 
    int startTime; // tussen 1 en 32
    int measureNumber;
    float velocity;
    Playable *track;
    virtual float getValue();

    static double calculateNoteFrequency(int aOctaveNumber, note_name aNoteName);

    Note(double aFreq, float aVelocity, int aDuration, int aMeasureNumber, int aStarttimeInsideMeasure, Playable *aTrack){
//      theta = 0;
        Note();
        frequency = aFreq;
        duration = aDuration;
        velocity = aVelocity;
        measureNumber = aMeasureNumber;
        startTime = aStarttimeInsideMeasure;
        track = aTrack;
    }

    Note(){
        theta = 0;
    }
    void toString();

};
```

**EDIT**

Here's the full compiler error message:

```
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.h:14:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:16:
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:19:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Note'
    vector<Note> notelist;
           ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:19:18: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    vector<Note> notelist;
                 ^~~~~~~~
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:23:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Note'
    vector<Note> getNotelist();
           ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:23:18: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    vector<Note> getNotelist();
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:24:18: error: unknown type name 'Note'
    void addNote(Note const &note){
                 ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:24:23: error: expected ')'
    void addNote(Note const &note){
                      ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Pattern.h:24:17: note: to match this '('
    void addNote(Note const &note){
                ^
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.h:14:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:17:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Synth.h:11:
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Oscillator.h:21:18: error: unknown type name 'Note'
    void setNote(Note &aNote);
                 ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Oscillator.h:23:20: error: unknown type name 'Note'
    float getValue(Note &note);
                   ^
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.h:14:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:17:
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Synth.h:47:21: error: unknown type name 'Note'
    float getSample(Note &note);
                    ^
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Note.h:14:
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:30:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Note'
        multimap<long, Note> noteList;
                       ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:30:23: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
        multimap<long, Note> noteList;
                             ^~~~~~~~
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:33:2: error: unknown type name 'Note'
        Note &addNoteAndReturnReference(Note &note);
        ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:33:34: error: unknown type name 'Note'
        Note &addNoteAndReturnReference(Note &note);
                                        ^
/Users/osxursnm/Development/SynthSequencer2/SynthSequencer2/Track.h:34:18: error: unknown type name 'Note'
        void removeNote(Note &note);
                        ^
14 errors generated.
```

Comment: You should add your compiler error message (the whole message) and real code so we can help you

Comment: I posted the compiler message code

Comment: I'm guessing you have an error in your Note.h file. Check you didn't forget a semicolon, maybe at the end of your class?

Comment: That's not it, I updated my question with the Note.h source

Comment: A lot of the errors refer to Pattern.h; what's that look like?

Comment: Post pattern.h, it looks like that's where the compiler can't find out what Note is...

Comment: @Sled Side note: `Note();` creates an anonymous object and doesn't affect the current object.

Comment: There's also Track.h and Synth.h so the problem must come from the Note files...

Comment: Here's the Patter.h code: http://pastie.org/private/td61xhwlqbmvqev1f3l98a I didn't change anything in that lately though

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My guess is that you have a cross-referencing problem.

In `Note.h` you include `Track.h` which uses an object of type `Note`. Use a forward declaration for `Note` in the `Track.h` file and include the `Note.h` file only in `Track.cpp`.

So try with

```
class Note;
```

before the declaration of class `Track` in the `Track.h` file and remove the `#include "Note.h"` statement at the beginning of the file.

Comment: This seems to fix the problem for the Track class but it looks like I'll need to be doing this for multiple classes. Any idea what can be causing this? I'm using `#ifndef` for each one of my classes and this didn't start happening until some hour ago. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sled you have circular dependencies between your header files: when the compiler processes `Note.h`, it finds the include of `Track.h`, then it starts processing `Track.h` and finds an object of type `Note`, which it doesn't know yet! Using guards doesn't help in this case. Unfortunately, when this circular dependency problem happens a lot of time, that is the the sign that your design should be revisited.